# Question about the number of zeros in the interval

Tags: algorithm, counting, prefix

There is a task where at first a sequence of numbers is given, and then several queries. In each request, an interval is indicated and it is necessary to say how many zeros are on it. There is a simple and efficient algorithm that uses prefix sums. But is there something better? Sorry for such a possibly stupid question from a newbie. (The improvement could be, for example, in speed, memory, or that the original sequence can be easily changed)

Comment: Please describe this efficient solution and its time complexity. Don't assume that this is well known.

Comment: By the way, technically, "efficient" means optimally fast.

Comment: test test test test

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford linear space, you can create a second array of the same size where the i'th entry has the number of zeros up to (and including) i in the original array. Then the query to get zeroes from j to k inclusive is arr[k] - arr[j-1] if j > 0, or simply arr[k] if j is zero.

This may be the simple and efficient approach your allude to. Each query is O(1), and the up-front work is O(n) time & O(n) space.

Potential improvements:

- If you don't care about preserving the input array, you could save space by overwriting it with the count of zeros array.
- If the size of the input is large relative to the (avg query size) * (number of queries), your total time will be less if you don't precompute anything and instead just scan the portion of the input being queried on each query. Total time will be improved by query-time will be slower.
- If the zeros are distributed according to some known formula, e.g., every even index has a zero, you can calculate the answer to a query in O(1) with no precomputation.